# java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl cannot be cast to class MyObject

Tags: java, spring, jax-rs

I'm attempting to make a parent class for an api response that comes from a webservice. Each response looks the same and within the "content" of the response is the actual varying object (can be Class A, Class B, etc.). So json response would be similar to:

```
{content:{a:a,b:b,c:c}}
```

I stripped down the classes so it's not cluttered

**Parent Class**:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)

public class ApiResponse<T> {
    
    List<T> content;

    public List<T> getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(List<T> content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

}
```

**Child Class**:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "")
public class ClassA extends ApiResponse<ClassA> {
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String b;
    //getters and setters

         @Override
            public void setContent(List<ClassA> content) { 
             super.content = content;
            }
}
```

When I run this and hit the endpoint I get the error in the subject of the post. When I make ApiResponse to be List instead of List and don't cast it works. I would like the parent class to be extended by a lot of other classes. Is there a better way to do this. If this is fine how can I resolve the cast error?

Comment: Why don't you make ApiResponse class generic?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha I just switched it to generic and still get the "ClassCastException: class org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl cannot be cast to class com.blah"

Comment: If you made it generic, you wouldn't have to cast anything.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha I'm not casting but I think in the background javax is attempting to, when I use above example and replace ? with the actual class like List<ClassA> it works, as soon as I make it generic/wildcard it has the casting issue

Comment: in the above example if I simply make it List<ClassA> and do a .getClass on the setList() in the parent class it's of type ClassA and it works. If I make it generic <T> and pass in <ClassA> into the parent it comes back as class org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl. So the parent class doesn't know to change it to ClassA which is what I'm trying to figure out

Comment: Have you been able to do any JSON to POJO at all? Maybe the provider you're using doesn't support it. I would suggest switching to the Jackson JSON provider.

Comment: Yes, I have it working as of now when I have the same redundant logic  in each response using jaxb annotations, seems like no matter what I did it would try to cast to that object type. I've also updated the question and added generics, still same result in the end. I'll try it with jackson